# Convert Android App that uses maps API V1 to Maps Android API V2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an android app that uses the old Maps API, it's now deprecated!

What steps I should take to make my app works with the new API.

I'm using also Distance Matrix API and Google Directions API.

my code will work with it ?!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can take a look at this blog post I wrote on how to create a Map application using:

[Google Map API V2 guide](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Basically the changes you would have to make are

**1.** Replace the `MapView` object with a `MapFragment` or `SupportMapFragment` object (depending on the `target SDK` of your application)

**2.** In additin you will have to repalce the `MapActivity` with a normal `Activity` (if you use the `MapFragment` object) or the `FragmentActivity` (if you use the `SupportMapFragment` object).

**3.** You will have to change the permissions in the manifest file to new ones, that are described in the guide.

Comment: is there need to change Mapkey?

Comment: Yes, of course. You will have to produce a new key for API V2.

Comment: Hi @vsk, No it won't. Overlays are not supported in API V2.

Comment: Hi Emil, in my app I'm using `com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint`, `com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem`, `com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay` etc. what should I do to convert into map v2??