# Is it mandatory to change the Google Map api V1 to V2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

In my app, I am using Google Map API V1 and it is in Google play; so is it mandatory to upgrade to V2 or I can go ahead with this for future? Regularly we are upgrading the app?

If I upgrade the Map API to V2, then do I need to change the app signing key?

Please help.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/

Comment: no its not mandatory for those application who are already registered with V1  but after the Depletion of V1 it is  neccessory to Work with either V2 or V3  further more You can read DOC


http://https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/

Answer (score 3):

The sad answer is that most of the objects of Google Map API V1 are replaced with new Objects in Google Map API V2.

For example instead of using GeoPoints you are going to use Latlng points. Overlays are gone as well and replaced with Polylines and Polygones.

Take a look at this answer I gave here:

[Convert Android App that uses maps API V1 to Maps Android API V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079093/convert-android-app-that-uses-maps-api-v1-to-maps-android-api-v2/16079262#16079262)

And have a look at this blog post I wrote that will get you started with Google Map API V2 implementation in your app:
[Google Map API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

So as you can understand most of the code should be rewritten to fit Google Map API V2.

Basically the changes you would have to make are

1. Replace the MapView object with a MapFragment or SupportMapFragment object (depending on the target SDK of your application)
2. In additin you will have to repalce the MapActivity with a normal Activity (if you use the MapFragment object) or the FragmentActivity (if you use the SupportMapFragment object).
3. You will have to change the permissions in the manifest file to new ones, that are described in the guide.

Yes of course you need to change the API key also....

Comment: Really? you wrote this post?

Answer (score 0):

No, your app will continue to work with V1 (for now).

You cannot get a new V1 license (old news, right, not since early 2013), but your current license is still valid.

At some point in the future, Google will likely decide to cut access to V1 - that is why they deprecated it, and that is why they have given us all plenty of warning.

Basically, we all "should" have started working with V2 in our new apps months ago, and by the time they choose to shut down V1, we "should" all be in a position to upgrade our old apps.

("should" i.e. in theory.... in practice, well, maybe not all of us are with V2 yet)

Comment: Thanks, But if upgrade to V2, my application signing key will be the same so i can release the next version of existing app?

Comment: Yes - your app signing key is different to your Maps API key. So you can upgrade Maps to V2 in a new version of existing app. (this is what we should be doing)