# Importing Google maps sample project and Google play services lib to Android studio

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm working with Android Studio 1.2.2 and I don't know how to solve this problem:

```
error: package com.google.android.maps does not exist.
```

I added these lines to may build.gradle file under dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

But the same error is appearing when I try to build the project.

[image]

Comment: Check to ensure that you have Maven Central as a repository.

 repositories {
    
    mavenCentral()

}

Comment: Is it essential that I use Maven in my project?

Comment: post your gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

You package name seems not correct, it should be:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
```

You need to follow the link [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start), or video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ADb5bNOFHE) to setup the map.

Make sure you compile latest play service:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

and include `permission, feature, mata-data(apikey and gems version)` in you `AndroidManifest` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bojie.map_basic_android" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!--
         The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR API KEY" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

For demo project you can refer [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMap-basic-android).

Comment: Please look at the screenshot above, I edited my question, as you can see I am trying to build an imported project that uses the com.google.android.maps package and I have no idea where can I find this package.

Comment: Oh, I see, I find that this package is very old or deprecated already, it maybe the google Map V1, right now we all use the Version2 and the package name is `com.google.android.gms.maps`, can you show me where you got the project?

Comment: Yes I realized that the project I imported is using a deprecated version of google maps, it's the Mixare open source project, an AR project for tracking geographic points of interest using the phone camera live view, look here http://www.mixare.org/

Comment: So maybe you can try to change the package from V1 to V2. You can refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16079093/convert-android-app-that-uses-maps-api-v1-to-maps-android-api-v2/16079262#16079262) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258307/is-it-mandatory-to-change-the-google-map-api-v1-to-v2).

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you have downloaded and installed the Google Play services SDK in your Android SDK Manager

Also you can try declaring this in your Manifest.xml

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Comment: I have the google play services downloaded and  <uses-library.../> added to the manifest but the error is still appearing.